# A preposition for this sentence

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

Consider:

> I had 2 (other?) packages **with/besides/in addition to/ together with** my bag and a flower which my student had given to me.

Or

> besides my bag, I had 2 other packages **with myself** and a flower which my student had given to me.

I think "with my bag" in sentence 1is ambiguous, so I look for a better preposition or rephrasing. Which ones do work?

In sentence 2 I'm not sure about "with my self".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first sentence, the correct way to phrase things would be:

> I had 2 packages, in addition to my bag and a flower, which my student had given to me

"other" isn't needed here, as you are focusing on the two packages.

The second sentence would then be:

> "Besides my bag, I had 2 other packages with me, and a flower, which my student gave to me"

"other" is suitable in this case, as you aren't focusing on the packages.

Comment: Is it one sentence more fluent than the other? Also, could you pleas say which other ones of prepositions work? Can all of them be used?

Comment: The fluency of the sentence depends on the object you want to focus on. If you want to focus on the two packages, the first sentence sounds more fluent, and if you are focusing on your bag and the flower, the second sentence is better.

Comment: For the prepositions (I didn't know yet that Enter means you post comments automatically, sorry for that): in the first sentence, "together with" and "in addition to" are most suitable, and the second sentence would be best in the manner as given in my original answer.

Comment: +1 for "with me".  *had given* is perfectly fine there. Small numbers are conventionally spelled out as a word, not written as a numeral: "two".